# How will you break down this part of a sentence? "弊社現在vtuberなどで使用されるアバターの制作"

Tags: meaning, particles, particle-に, particle-で, sentence

> 初めて。ｄｍ失礼いたします。こちら株式会社companyname営業部門となります。弊社現在vtuberなどで使用されるアバターの制作並びに、コミュニティー事業をしている者なのですがまだ活動をされていない方あるいはすでにvtuber活動をされている方も含めてvtuberにご興味がある方を探しておりまして、ご自身、もしくは他の方で弊社サービスを用いたvtuber活動にご興味のある方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか？

I was told that "弊社現在vtuberなどで使用されるアバターの制作" Would mean "currently, we are making avatars used by vtubers".

- But wouldn't it be などに instead of などで, since it is a passive and などで probably means that it is used as an instrument?

Comment: Yeah, that's a very grammatically confused message as writing. The writer must have directly output what they'd say it orally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for parsing, there is an omission of は: 弊社**は**. So the structure of the sentence is:

- 弊社は、[現在vtuberなどで..事業をしている]者なのですが、

so that a literal translation would be *our company is a guy that currently makes avatars used by vtubers and do some community activities*.

弊社は..者なのですが is already a bit strange (like *our company is a guy*), and 'vtuberなどで' is most likely to be a confusion of vtuber and platform (like youtube) for which で is appropriate (or they thought *vtuber* means both people and platform). As you are aware, 'vtuberに' is more regular.

Comment: 者 is not that strange because [it can refer to an organization](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/82714/5010), although it may be wise to avoid this usage outside legal contexts.